# ng-repeat or something similar on two arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I recently started learning `angular js`. I have following object `ResultRow`:

```
ResultRow = function ( cars, prices) { //cars and prices are arrays
        this.prices = prices; 
        this.cars = cars;
};
```

for example,

```
ResultsRow=new ResultsRow(["Ford","Honda","Nissan"],[20,22,18]);
```

I want to display the `ResultsRow`  in table as:

```
Car            Price
Ford            20
Honda           22
Nissan          18
```

So basically print car[0],price[0] in one table row, car[1], price[1] in next table row and so on.

I tried following using `ng-repeat`:

```
<tr>
   <td ng-repeat="car in ctrl.ResultsRow.cars">
   {{car}}
   </td>
   <td ng-repeat="car in ctrl.ResultsRow.prices">
   {{price}}
   </td>
</tr>
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to display the exact format that I want. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S. It is quite complicated for me to change the format of ResultRow as I am generating it after quite a few data operations.

Answer (score 1):

You should make an array of objects with properties to iterate in stead of trying to simultaneously iterate two separate arrays.

Example:

```
var row1 = {
    car: "Ford",
    price: 20
};
var row2 = {
    car: "Honda",
    price: 22
}; 
$scope.rows = [row1, row2];
```

Then in the template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td>{{row.car}}</td>
    <td>{{row.price}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It is *$scope.rows* not *var rows*.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use a multi-dimension array then I would suggest use `new Array` and if your car array and price array content is in order then you could do something like this;

```
vm.ResultsRow=new Array(["Ford","Honda","Nissan"],[20,22,18]);

<tr  ng-repeat="car in vm.ResultsRow[0]">
     <td>
     {{car}}
     </td> 
     <td>
      {{vm.ResultsRow[1][$index]}}
     </td> 
</tr>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
 var vm = this;
vm.ResultsRow=new Array(["Ford","Honda","Nissan"],[20,22,18]);
 

console.log(vm.ResultsRow)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
 <table>
   <tr  ng-repeat="car in vm.ResultsRow[0]">
     <td>
     {{car}}
     </td> 
     <td>
      {{vm.ResultsRow[1][$index]}}
     </td> 
  </tr> 
 </table> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change the function for mapping data, like this :

```
var repeatObject = new Array();
ResultRow = function ( cars, prices) { //cars and prices are arrays
    if(cars.length == prices.length) {
        for(let i in cars){
            this.repeatObject.push({'cars' : cars[i], 'prices' : prices[i]});
        }
    }
};
```

So you can use 'ng-repeat' :

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in repeatObject">
  <td>{{row.car}}</td>
  <td>{{row.price}}</td>
</tr>
```